# Quotient of compactly supported functions where denomiator has larger support.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $ \phi, \varphi \in \mathcal{D} $ are given test functions and $ \text{Supp} \ \varphi \subseteq \text{Supp} \ \phi $. I have used many times in my PDE class that the quotient $ \varphi / \phi $ is well-defined and smooth because $  \phi $ vanishes on sets where $ \varphi $ vanishes.

I have never quiet thought this through. What is the right point of view in looking at the well-definedness of this function? Is it that we assign the value zero to the expression $0/0$, or perhaps any other reason? Is this statement even correct, in the sense that there has to be some additional assumption on the support? In particular, if $ \phi \in \mathcal{D}$. Then since $ \text{Supp} \ \phi' \subseteq \text{Supp} \ \phi $ , does it make sense to write $ \phi' / \phi$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You meant $\phi$ has no zeros in its support. For $\phi'/\phi$ try with $\phi(x) = e^{-1/x^2}1_{x > 0}$

Comment: A piece of unrelated advice: $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the same symbol. It's confusing do use both, it's like you would use "a" and "$a$" as two symbols. Rather, use $\phi$ and $\theta$, or $\varphi$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @5xum Mixing $\phi,\varphi$ is the common notation for functions in $C^\infty_c$

Comment: @reuns Are you sure you aren't talking about mixing $\Phi$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: @Meagain $e^{-1/x^2}1_{x > 0}$ is the first example of a smooth function vanishing for $x < 0$ and $e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x| < 1}$ is the first example in $C^\infty_c$

Comment: Thanks! But this counter example is where differentiating do not shrink the support. If the inclusion of supports is strict, then I believe the claim would hold?

Comment: Differentation cannot "shrink the support" in the way you think